# Cannot add Id tag using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add a custom id tag e.g. `id = keys[key][each]`as part of the html that's being appended to the `new_resumes` class e.g. I would like

```
<div class = "filtered_results" id = keys[key][each] ...
```

instead with the code below - when I use the `attr` or `prop` tag it adds an id to the new resumes class. I appreciate my code is not the greatest.

```
for (var key in keys) {
    $(".new_resumes").append("<div class='filtered_results' style='color:white; background-color:red; text-align:center; height:20px; line-height: 20px'>" + key + "</div>");
    for (var each in keys[key]) {
        $(".new_resumes").append("<div class='filtered_results' style ='height:60px; text-align:center; height:60px; line-height: 60px;'>" + keys[key][each][0] + "</div>").prop('id',keys[key][each][0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to add the ID to the `filtered_results` div you are creating?

You should just concatenate it like so:

```
$(".new_resumes").append("<div class='filtered_results' id='" +keys[key][each][0] +"' style ='height:60px; text-align:center; height:60px; line-height: 60px;'>" + keys[key][each][0] + "</div>")
```

Take note of this part: `id='" +keys[key][each][0] +"'`

Right now, you are calling `.prop` on the current element which is still the `.new_resumes` element.